Website links between html files. Making a website and I have the mainscreen.html file with a about button to about.html
Website links between html files. Making a website and I have the mainscreen.html file with an about button to navigate about.html. I can open the files separately by using google chrome from intellij but when on the mainscreen page and i click the about button i get a 404 error. I cannot figure about what i have done wrong in the controllers or html files to link the two. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@Controller
public class AboutController {

    @GetMapping("/about")
    public String showAboutPage() {
        return "about";
    }

    @GetMapping("/mainscreen")
    public String backToMainScreen() {
        return "redirect:/mainscreen";
    }
}

package com.example.demo.controllers;

import com.example.demo.domain.Part;
import com.example.demo.domain.Product;
import com.example.demo.service.PartService;
import com.example.demo.service.ProductService;
import org.jboss.jandex.Main;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 *
 * mainscreen controller
 *
 */


@Controller
public class MainScreenController {
    // private final PartRepository partRepository;
    // private final ProductRepository productRepository;'

    private PartService partService;
    private ProductService productService;

    private List<Part> theParts;
    private List<Product> theProducts;

    /* public MainScreenController(PartRepository partRepository, ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.partRepository = partRepository;
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }*/

    public MainScreenController(PartService partService, ProductService productService) {
        this.partService = partService;
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/mainscreen")
    public String listPartsandProducts(Model theModel, @Param("partkeyword") String partkeyword, @Param("productkeyword") String productkeyword) {
        // add to the spring model
        List<Part> partList = partService.listAll(partkeyword);
        theModel.addAttribute("parts", partList);
        theModel.addAttribute("partkeyword", partkeyword);
        // theModel.addAttribute("products", productService.findAll());
        List<Product> productList = productService.listAll(productkeyword);
        theModel.addAttribute("products", productList);
        theModel.addAttribute("productkeyword", productkeyword);
        return "mainscreen";
    }
}


my link on about.html is:
<a href="/mainscreen" class="btn btn-primary">Back to Main Screen</a>

my link on mainscreen.html is:
<a href="/about" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mb-3">About</a>

I have tried checking syntax and troubleshooting springboot.

I don't know anything about the framework but noticed you are linking to "about" instead of "about.html". Could that be the reason?

You can [edit] your question. Hence you don't need (and should not) post question details in comments. This time, David has done it for you.

backToMainScreen on the AboutController appears confusing. It listens at /mainscreen and then redirects to /mainscreen (again). At the same time, you have a mapping for the main screen in the MainScreenController. Check if there is/are (a) problem(s) there and also post any log messages on the server side.

I suppose you are learning Thymeleaf which is the default MVC library of Spring Boot.
Here are some basic information you will need:
How to display a static HTML page? (without any MVC functionality)
Place you HTML file in the directory src/main/resources/static/about.html. In the HTML page call it with plain HTML syntax:
href="/about.html"

How to display a dynamic Thymeleaf HTML template?
Place the template file in the directory src/main/resources/templates/about.html. In the template HTML page call the controller endpoint with following Thymeleaf specific syntax:
th:href="@{/about-controller}"

Define a controller like this:
@Controller
public class AboutController {
    @GetMapping("/about-controller")
    public String showAboutPage() {
        return "about.html";
        // will work as well:
        // return "about";
    }
}

Please note I have used different names for the controller and the template. This is not obligatory but will help one understand the difference.
Please also note that you can omit the extension .html as it will be added internally.
